# MacBook Air M1 `/dev/cu.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port` device readable but not writable

Tags: command-line, bluetooth, permission

I'm currently experimenting with the Bluetooth serial port on my MacBook Air M1 Ventura 13.3. I've installed the "Serial Bluetooth Terminal" app on my Android phone and have successfully used it to connect and communicate with various BT serial devices, such as ELM327 interfaces. I've paired my phone with my MacBook and launched screen /dev/cu.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port to try sending messages. While I'm able to send messages from my Android device to my MacBook and see them appear in screen, sending messages back from my MacBook to my Android device doesn't seem to work. I've also tried using /dev/tty.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port but encountered the same issue.

Is it possible that the Bluetooth device is somehow in read-only mode? And if so, is there a way to configure it to allow communication in both directions?

Comment: The name of the of the port containing “incoming” would seem to preclude writing to something that is be definition, can only be read.

Comment: By incoming I understand that this is the listening side of the connection establishing process, connection is initiated by phone in my case, it does not imply how the communication happens later, that's at least how I understand it.

Comment: It’s what is coming *from* the BT device.  Trying to write to this device It’s like  trying to sing  into a speaker and not a microphone.

Comment: That's quite surprising for me because when I set up an incoming port on a Windows machine and connect to it from either an Android phone or a MacBook, the communication is bi-directional. It seems that this is a new learning for me, that Apple thinks differently.